# "follow the tutorial" vs. "follow along the tutorial"

Tags: word-usage, colloquial-language

[From a tutorial](https://www.facebook.com/qt/posts/1989735104394469?comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22O%22%7D)

> **Follow along the tutorial** to build an automotive user interface and create a #UI like that of your very own embedded device!

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=follow%20along%20the%20tutorial%2C%20follow%20the%20tutorial&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfollow%20the%20tutorial%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfollow%20the%20tutorial%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFollow%20the%20tutorial%3B%2Cc0) shows writers only use "follow the tutorial" rather than "follow along the tutorial"

[image]

Is that because "follow along the tutorial" is a colloquial expression?

Comment: I'm sure the text you're citing didn't come from a native speaker. There isn't really a question here - it's just a random fragment from an nns who incorrectly included the unwanted preposition ***along*** with transitive ***follow [some argument, demonstration, text,...]***.

Comment: That's to say, you can ***follow your nose***, but you can't validly ***follow along your nose*** in English.

Comment: To my ears, the most natural (close) relation to `follow along...` would be `follow along with the tutorial`. That's only one dropped word, so quite plausible as a simple mistake.

Comment: To add to the last comment, *follow along **to** the tutorial* would also be okay.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you. What does "nns" stand for?

Comment: non-native speaker (non-native ***Anglophone**!* :)

Comment: @JasonBassford: Maybe Canadian (US?) English is different. In my understanding as a Brit, you can (just about) ***sing** along **to** [the radio, music,...]*, but for ***follow*** only *...along **with*** really works (if you *insist* on having prepositions where they're not actually needed). Whatever - prepositions are inherently "slippery" in English.